How to calculate size of Option<String> for Anchor accounts
I saw on the docs that the size for Option<T> is 1 + space(T), but considering that T is a String, how can I know the size when initializing an account?
#[account]
pub struct UserAccount {
    pub name: Option<String>,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(name: Option<String>)]
pub struct InitializeUser<'info> {
    #[account(
        init,
        payer = signer,
        space = 8 + (1 + name.len()), // How can I calculate this?
        seeds = [signer.key().as_ref()],
        bump
    )]
    pub user: Account<'info, UserAccount>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub signer: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}


Hey there to calculate the size of an Option< String > when initializing an account in Anchor, you need to consider the size of the Option itself, which is always 1 byte, plus the size of the String (4 + length of string in bytes).
Regarding the size of each character in the string, since strings in Rust are UTF-8 encoded by default, characters can occupy different numbers of bytes. Common English characters (such as letters, numbers, and ASCII symbols) typically occupy 1 byte each
. Therefore, when determining the size of the String, you can assume that each character accounts for 1 byte of space. 1 + ( 4+ // length of string in bytes)
Source : Anchor Docs
